# Parallel Map (Generator) Operator

Tags: concurrency, functional-programming, generator, semantics, language-design

I am interested in defining a parallel map operator for my language. It transforms a list into a new list given an expression. It would have a syntax similar to a generator. Unlike generators in C# and Python, it would potentially be evaluated in parallel, if the compiler desires (e.g. there is an idle core, and the list is really big). It would be called `witheach` to distinguish it from `foreach` which is executed sequentially.

For example consider:

```
var f = function(int x) : int { return x * 2; }
var my_list = 0..1000000;
var my_mapped_list = witheach (i in mylist) yield f(i);
```

My question is, is this going to be too unintuitive for programmers who may put side-effects in `f`? Of course, I would say not to do this in the documentation, but most programmers don't read language documentation. :-)

I guess the bigger question, is can modern day programmers adapt to implicit parallel list processing semantics in their language, or do they need things to be more explicit?

Comment: "do they need things to be more explicit" -- yeah, don't call it "witheach" but "WARNING_DO_NOT_SIDE_EFFECT_HERE_PARALLEL_MAP".

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a bit tounge in cheek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that most users won't read the documentation, and as such will probably put non-thread safe code in a `witheach` block (especially with a name and syntax so similar to `foreach`). You'll either have to trust your users, or perform some static analysis on the concurrent safety of that block. If you chose the later, then you may as well not bother with `witheach` - just automatically parallelise `foreach` when possible.

As to whether users are ready for the responsibility of choosing to be potentially dangerous, I would wager "yes", as long as they know up front what is safe. Many languages force you to make this choice each day (pointers, manual memory management, shared memory concurrency). You might want to make your syntax less ambiguous (i.e. call it `parallelforeach`), so that people know what they're signing up for.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [pmap](http://clojure.org/api#toc429)?

Comment: Yes, it is practically the same thing, just with a more Java-ish syntax.